# Change color upon change of counter

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have the following element in a .JSP file

```
<h:commandLink value="#{g_msgs.newIncoming} (#{notify.acknowledgedCounter}) "  
id="counter"
rendered="#{(mainPage.user) !=null}"
action="#{menu.selItemForNewIncoming}"
style="padding-right:15px"
/>
```

I want to chnage the color of counter to red when the counter changes value

p.s. this counter is checked every 5 secs with ajax poll

```
here is the ajax poll
<a4j:poll id="poll" interval="5000" reRender="counter" rendered="#{(mainPage.user) !=null}" action="#{notify.loadNea}" oncomplete="clickNotification('#{rich:clientId('showNotificationLink')}')" />
```

i have tried this in javascript

```
document.getElementById(counter).onchange = function(){checkCounter()};

function checkCounter(){
    var counter = document.getElementById(counter).value;
    if(counter == 'true'){
      counter.style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: I approve, now do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show what you tried and show the ajax code which is where you want to add the css change: `var fld = document.getElementById("counter"); fld.value=valueFromAjax; fld.className= (valueFromAjax<0) ? "negative":"positive";`

Your counter needs to be in quotes and onchange is not triggered by the ajax

Comment: Still not working. Maybe it needs another approach.